# I don't understand what a Fundamental group is

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I have been staring at the definition for days, drew diagrams but I don't understand as to **what its elements are**

> The fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x)$ at a base point $x$ is a set of rel $\{0,1\}$ homotopy classes $[\alpha]$ of closed paths $\alpha: I \to X$ such that
>
> $$\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=x \in X$$
>
> with concatenation of paths as its operation.

Now, looking at this, I drew a diagram. Draw some $X$ and a point $x$ in it. The condition

> $$\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=x \in X$$

tells me I am looking at *only* paths that start from $x$ and end at $x$. i.e. A *loop*. Of course, I can draw various and various loops. One that looks like an oval, one that could go all over $X$ and come back to $x$, or the constant path.

By the homotopy rel $\{0,1\}$ condition, I consider some homotopy $h$ between paths(loops) that give

> $$h(0,t)=\alpha(0)=\beta(0) \text{ and } h(1,t)=\alpha(1)=\beta(1)$$

For any loops $\alpha,\beta$ with base point $x$.

Now I must admit; I am very confused with the amount of fancy words here, homotopies, rel $B$, paths, base point, homotopy classes etc.

But looking at the above, I thought "doesn't a rel $\{0,1\}$ homotopy exist between any two loops in $X$ about $x$?" Namely, this leads to the (wrong) conclusion that there is only *one* element in the fundamental group since homotopy is an equivalence relation and we are considering its equivalence classes(homotopy class).

Because,

> Any loop about $x$ in $X$ have the property $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=x \in X$. So these types of paths are the ones we consider. By definition of a homotopy between some $\alpha, \beta$,
>
> $$h(s,0)=\alpha(s) \text{ and } h(s,1)=\beta(s)$$
>
> For any two given paths, let me define $h(s,t)=(1-t)\alpha(s)+t\beta(s)$. Then,
>
> $$h(s,0)=\alpha(s), h(s,1)=\beta(s)$$
>
> Thus a homotopy between $\alpha,\beta$. Furthermore, as mentioned earlier we only consider loops based at $x$ so we have for both $\alpha,\beta$
>
> $$h(0,t)=(1-t)\alpha(0)+t\beta(0)=\alpha(0)-t\alpha(0)+t\beta(0)$$
>
> Since $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=x=\beta(0)=\beta(1)$ as a loop,
>
> $$\alpha(0)-t\alpha(0)+t\beta(0)=\alpha(0)=\beta(0)$$
>
> We can compute $h(1,t)$ in the exact same way to obtain $\alpha(1)=\beta(1)=h(1,t)$, namely giving us $h(s,t)$ as the homotopy rel $\{0,1\}$. Then, since $\alpha,\beta$ were arbitrary loops we can define such homotopy for any two loops about the base point $x$. Therefore, by transitivity of homotopy as equivalence relations, I have that every loop is homotopic rel $\{0,1\}$ to each other.
>
> $\alpha \sim \beta \Leftrightarrow \exists h(s,t):\alpha \cong \beta$ such that $h$ is homotopy rel $\{0,1\}$.
>
> Namely, every loop is homotpic rel $\{0,1\}$ to each thereby we only ave *one* equivalence class. i.e. the elements of the fundamental group turns out to be only one.

So that's my reasoning. Of course I know it's wrong, but I don't know **why** it's wrong. A misunderstanding of definitions? Abuse of definitions? Abuse of logic? What drove me in this wrong direction?

I really need help on this

Comment: In general spaces $X$, the expression $(1-t)\alpha(s) + t\beta(s)$ doesn't make sense. It makes sense when your $X$ is e.g. a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but unless the subset is convex (in which case its fundamental group _is_ trivial), you can probably find loops $\alpha,\beta$ such that for some $(s,t) \in [0,1]^2$ you have $(1-t)\alpha(s) + t\beta(s) \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus X$. Consider $X = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, the constant loop $\alpha \equiv 1$, and the unit circle $\beta(s) = (\cos(2\pi s),\sin(2\pi s))$.

Comment: Hi, why does it not make sense...? I remember seeing examples of homotpies between two continuouos functions $f,g:X \to Y$ defined in that way... I really don't get the rules in algebraic topology, when you can do what because why and when you can't!

Comment: When we're dealing with (topological) subspaces of a real vector space, the expression makes sense (but may denote a point outside the subspace). But in general spaces, neither multiplication with real numbers, nor addition are defined.